# JavaFX textarea listeners

Tags: javafx, keylistener, arrow-keys

Is it possible to turn off `arrow key` listeners in `TextArea` when it has focus. I am reffering mostly to moving scrollpane with them when there is more text than space in area. I'm trying to avoid this.

Thanks for suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

You could use an event filter. Filters receive events during the event capturing phase (1st, down the scene graph) of event processing, whereas handlers are triggered during the event bubbling phase (2nd, up the scene graph). Have a look at this snippet:

```
TextArea textArea = new TextArea();
textArea.addEventFilter(KeyEvent.ANY, event -> {
    KeyCode code = event.getCode();
    boolean isArrowKey = code == KeyCode.UP || code == KeyCode.RIGHT
            || code == KeyCode.DOWN || code == KeyCode.LEFT;
    if (isArrowKey) {
        event.consume();
    }
});
```

The `consume()` method stops further propagation of the event. As a result, no (key event) listener will be triggered. But this also disables the ability to navigate through the arrow keys—is that really what you want?

**EDIT:** in regards to [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41527863/javafx-textarea-listeners/41528215#comment70262529_41528215), [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37470864/3429133) states:

> The behavior for controlling the scroll bars is internally coded in the TextAreaSkin (which in Java 8 is not part of the public JavaFX API). You could copy or subclass the TextAreaSkin to customize its behavior and then [attach your customized skin to your node](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#control). This is really the "proper" way to customize internal control behavior in the way in which you wish.

Comment: Not exactly. I want to turn off these particular listeners which make scrollpane in `TextArea` move with arrows but want to have my own onKeyPressed events with them. Right now I have action implemented by myself + from JavaFX Api together. Point is to turn off the second one. I hope it is more clear now.

Comment: The `if (textArea.isFocused())` is redundant: the text area will not fire the key event if it is not focused. @Saris It's not really clear why this doesn't do what you want. Just add your own functionality in the `if (isArrowKey)` block.